# HTTP Basic Auth and Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In an in Azure Functions with HTTP trigger, where in the HttpRequestMessage instance are the credentials (username and password) in a basic HTTP Authentication scheme?

Answer (score 7):

I was able to find a username:password string encoded in base64 in:

```
request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter
```

Where `request` is an instance of `HttpRequestMessage`

Comment: Yup, you just need to handle the base64 decode and secret matching yourself and you should be good. A function key sent in URL or header would be much easier to use here since the authorization logic happens before your Function even gets called, of course your remote caller needs to be flexible enough to use that instead of basic Auth. The crucial difference is that for function keys you don't pay for unauthorized calls (401s), but for basic Auth, since your code gets called for every request, you'll get billed for the 401s as well.

Answer (score 2):

Basic is not an option, nor is any other commonplace auth scheme available right now, unfortunately. Other than Anonymous, HTTP Functions auth is based on keys generated and stored in Azure. Three types of keys are currently available:

- `Admin` - requires a "host" key (host keys are shared by all functions)
- `System` - requires the special "master" host key
- `Functions` - requires a key defined for the individual function

Keys are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#authorization-keys) and can be managed from the "Manage" button when you expand a given Function in the portal.

Microsoft is working on adding a new token-based `User` auth type based on tokens instead of keys. You can read about it in the following github issue:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/33

Comment: Thanks. That token-based User auth type looks promissory!